# At night server responds with 324 status (but it works in daytime and always over HTTPS)

Tags: networking

I have a CPanel server with 5 IPs and a few domains.

During night, access to main domain through HTTP return 324 no response many times. After several refresh it comes but many assets won't load and return 324. Using HTTPS is fine. During day HTTP is also fine.

But another domain on that very sever works fine all the day through HTTP.

The server DNS are ns1 and ns2 of the first domain. 
Second domain is on the shared IP and first domain has a dedicated IP.

I cant resolve the problem :( and appreciate any help so much!

Comment: I found out that it is not related to domain.
When I connect to shared IP it works. But dedicated IP doesn't :(

Comment: Can't see why this was migrated to SU. Jared is right.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the firewall or software used somewhere on the server has restricted access times. Contact the server provider.